# canvas描画時のmouseupイベントの遅延の原因

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

※　描画は矩形であることが前提の質問になります。

下記のようなコードでcanvasに矩形を描画しています。
mouseupイベントのみが遅延して発生するのですが原因がわかりません。

- 遅延の時間はその時々です。
- mousemove内の処理は描画以外何も行っていません。
- mousemoveの処理を外しても遅延発生は変わりませんでした。
- canvasでのみ発生しています。（同アプリ内のmouseupは問題なく動きます）

原因をご存知の方いましたら、ご回答お願いいたします。

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (evt){
　　　　draw = true;
});
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt){
　　　　if(draw){
　　　　　　　　ctx.fillRect(evt.layerX, evt.layerY, 5, 5);
　　　　}
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function (evt){
　　　　draw = false;
});
```

Comment: 遅延して発生するというのは、どのように確認されましたか？違うPCやブラウザでも発生しますか？動作するサンプルをjsfiddleで作ってみましたが、これでも再現するでしょうか？ http://jsfiddle.net/cbwqxt1j/1/

Comment: ありがとうございます。

＞遅延して発生するというのは、どのように確認されましたか？
デバッガにコールスタックを打って、mouseup動作をしコールスタックに入るまでを見ています。

＞違うPCやブラウザでも発生しますか？
ブラウザはchromeが動けばOKなのでchrome以外は確認していません。

＞動作するサンプルをjsfiddleで作ってみましたが...
発生しませんでした。
自分もローカルで同じものを作りましたが発生しませんね...
どん詰まり状態です（涙）